# FTP client with live preview

Tags: windows, ftp, live-preview

I am looking for a FTP client that:

- runs on Microsoft Windows
- can open a file located on the server and refresh it whenever it gets changed on the server.

Ideally: gratis.

---

WinSCP and FileZilla can open a file from the server, but it does not refresh it whenever it gets changed on the server. (at least I haven't found a way to do so)

[image]

[image]